# MacOSX: How to get text that is VoiceOver currently speaking?

Tags: python, macos, applescript

I have to get text that VoiceOver speaks at that moment.

VoiceOver has the feature named caption panel that shows that text on the display, but it seems that you can't grab the text from inside it using applescript.

It would be ideal if I can register as a synthesizer and get it in this manner, but nobody succeeded yet in doing it. As far as I can tell, Apple is keeping that documentation out.

You can get text that is under voiceover cursor, keyboard cursor or mouse cursor, but the returned text is too broad and doesn't reflect what is being said.

So I am planning to yank out the text from VoiceOver directly, by any mean possible.

Python solution would be great, but any language would do.

Answer (score -1):

once you've set up VoiceOver, then just use an input text box, (any language), hit 2 times the 'fn' key to start speech recognition, say, and hit 'fn' key to stop recording. (in my case, the short cut for voice over in system préférences in 'fn' key).

I tested it with Applescript bellow :

```
 set myText to display dialog "Tell me what you want after activation via fn key" default answer ""
```

the variable myText contains the text I said.

Comment: You're writing about dictation i.e. voice recognition. VoiceOver is a screen reader, not speech recognizer. Good to know that you can access dictation through applescript too anyway.